# Python Generators and how to iterate over correctly to drop records based on a key within the dictionary being present in a a separate list

Tags: python, generator

I'm new to the concept of generators and I'm struggling with how to apply my changes to the records within the generator object returned from the RISparser module.

I understand that a generator only reads a record at a time and doesn't actually store the data in memory but I'm having a tough time iterating over it effectively and applying my changes.

My changes will involve dropping records that have not got ['doi'] values that are contained within a list of DOIs [doi_match].

```
doi_match = ['10.1002/14651858.CD008259.pub2','10.1002/14651858.CD011552','10.1002/14651858.CD011990']
```

Generator object returned form RISparser contains the following information, this is just the first 2 records returned of a few 100. I want to iterate over it and compare the 'doi': key from the generator with the list of DOIs.

```
{'type_of_reference': 'JOUR', 'title': "The CoRe Outcomes in WomeN's health (CROWN) initiative: Journal editors invite researchers to develop core outcomes in women's health", 'secondary_title': 'Neurourology and Urodynamics', 'alternate_title1': 'Neurourol. Urodyn.', 'volume': '33', 'number': '8', 'start_page': '1176', 'end_page': '1177', 'year': '2014', 'doi': '10.1002/nau.22674', 'issn': '07332467 (ISSN)', 'authors': ['Khan, K.'], 'keywords': ['Bias (epidemiology)', 'Clinical trials', 'Consensus', 'Endpoint determination/standards', 'Evidence-based medicine', 'Guidelines', 'Research design/standards', 'Systematic reviews', 'Treatment outcome', 'consensus', 'editor', 'female', 'human', 'medical literature', 'Note', 'outcomes research', 'peer review', 'randomized controlled trial (topic)', 'systematic review (topic)', "women's health", 'outcome assessment', 'personnel', 'publication', 'Female', 'Humans', 'Outcome Assessment (Health Care)', 'Periodicals as Topic', 'Research Personnel', "Women's Health"], 'publisher': 'John Wiley and Sons Inc.', 'notes': ['Export Date: 14 July 2020', 'CODEN: NEURE'], 'type_of_work': 'Note', 'name_of_database': 'Scopus', 'custom2': '25270392', 'language': 'English', 'url': 'https://www.scopus.com/inward/record.uri?eid=2-s2.0-84908368202&amp;doi=10.1002%2fnau.22674&amp;partnerID=40&amp;md5=b220702e005430b637ef9d80a94dadc4'}
{'type_of_reference': 'JOUR', 'title': "The CROWN initiative: Journal editors invite researchers to develop core outcomes in women's health", 'secondary_title': 'Gynecologic Oncology', 'alternate_title1': 'Gynecol. Oncol.', 'volume': '134', 'number': '3', 'start_page': '443', 'end_page': '444', 'year': '2014', 'doi': '10.1016/j.ygyno.2014.05.005', 'issn': '00908258 (ISSN)', 'authors': ['Karlan, B.Y.'], 'author_address': 'Gynecologic Oncology and Gynecologic Oncology Reports, India', 'keywords': ['clinical trial (topic)', 'decision making', 'Editorial', 'evidence based practice', 'female infertility', 'health care personnel', 'human', 'outcome assessment', 'outcomes research', 'peer review', 'practice guideline', 'premature labor', 'priority journal', 'publication', 'systematic review (topic)', "women's health", 'editorial', 'female', 'outcome assessment', 'personnel', 'publication', 'Female', 'Humans', 'Outcome Assessment (Health Care)', 'Periodicals as Topic', 'Research Personnel', "Women's Health"], 'publisher': 'Academic Press Inc.', 'notes': ['Export Date: 14 July 2020', 'CODEN: GYNOA', 'Correspondence Address: Karlan, B.Y.; Gynecologic Oncology and Gynecologic Oncology ReportsIndia'], 'type_of_work': 'Editorial', 'name_of_database': 'Scopus', 'custom2': '25199578', 'language': 'English', 'url': 'https://www.scopus.com/inward/record.uri?eid=2-s2.0-84908351159&amp;doi=10.1016%2fj.ygyno.2014.05.005&amp;partnerID=40&amp;md5=ab5a4d26d52c12d081e38364b0c79678'}
```

I tried iterating over the generator and applying the changes. But the records that have matches are not being placed in the match list.

```
match = []
for entry in ris_records:
    if entry['doi'] in doi_match:
        match.append(entry)    
    else:
        del entry
```

any advice on how to iterate over a generator correctly, thanks.

Comment: There is no real benefit in the `del entry` - the object will be destroyed automatically when the reference to it is removed on the next iteration by reassigning `entry` to point to the next item (unless there are other references elsewhere, but in that case the `del entry` would not free up the memory either). So omit the `else:` part.

Comment: Separate from the above comment, the inclusion testing would be more efficient if `doi_match` was a set rather than a list.

Comment: Final comment - obviously in your example, you are building a list (`match`), so you will end up with at least the matching records all present in memory together. If in fact you are using these only to iterate over (once), then it would make sense to instead write your own generator function which iterates over the input generator and yields the relevant items for the calling code to then process. You can also use a generator expression for this: `(entry for entry in ris_records if entry['doi'] in doi_match)`

Comment: @alaniwi Thanks, final comment - so that generator function would involve applying my comparison and yielding the result as what? another generator object?

Comment: If you write a generator function (rather than using the expression in my previous comment) then the code in it would look your existing code but just with `yield entry` in place of `match.append(entry)` (and without the `match=[]` at the start). You would call the function to get the iterator, and then when you iterate over it, that is when the code in the function itself would really be run.

Comment: Given all the caveats above (use a set instead of a list for `doi_match`, remove the pointless `del entry` statement) then your approach *should work* if indeed any of the `entry['doi']` strings match any of the strings in `doi_match`...

Comment: @alaniwi What is the advantage in using the set, an ordered version of the dictionary yes but any other reason?

Comment: @EoinVaughan The time taken to test whether an element exists in a list increases linearly with the length of the list (unless you happen to find an early match), but if you use a set then the time should be roughly the same, regardless of the number of elements.

Comment: @alaniwi I'm still hitting a snag, I don't seem to be able to iterate the generator created from the generator function. I get the error ```StopIteration:```, why would this be? I believe this means there mustn't be anything in the generator object created but there should be 89 records as per my comparison in my own script.

Comment: @EoinVaughan I think I would need to see in more detail what exactly you are trying. `StopIteration` is raised when there are no more items, but if you are iterating (using a `for` loop or similar) then it should automatically catch this and exit the loop so that you never see the exception explicitly in your code.

Comment: @alaniwi Yes I only get this exception when I ```print(next(iterator))``` and not for the loop. I did this to check if anything was in fact being read from the generator. I'm just a bit confused as to what I'm doing when I get the generator object from the RISparser module and then I call a generator function on that generator to apply my changes is all.

Comment: Yes if you call `next` yourself then you will have to catch any `StopIteration` that will be raised if there are no more items. Remember that you can only iterate over it *once*. So if you are doing a `for` loop and then afterwards you are using `next` with the same iterator, then the iterations will be exhausted and you will certainly get `StopIteration`...

Comment: ... If you will need to iterate over your iterator multiple times, then you will either have to call the input generator function again each time you restart the iterations, or you will have to go back to what you were doing previously and just store the values in a list (which will negate some of the memory advantages of using generator in the first place).